# JQuery autodividersSelector not grouping posts correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

First I would like to thank you for taking your time to look at this question. Much appreciated.

**Request:**
My initial intention was to group all posts by week of a year i.e all posts in Week 45 grouped together using the divider but have changed my mind to something easier so I could easily code it. I now want it grouped by date of post.

**Efforts so far:**
I came across the autodividersSelector function and tried implementing it. It appears to work but the result isn't correct. The output is grouping all the posts in just one divider under one date instead of splitting the divider by date posted. See diagram below:

[image]
Please review the code below and advise where I might be getting it wrong or if I am applying it in the correct format. I am happy to continue investigation as learning curve with your help. Thanks in advance

**HTML Code:**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blogposts', function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/?json=recentstories" ,
    dataType: "json" ,
    beforeSend: function () {$('.loader').show();},
    complete: function () {$('.loader').hide();},
    success: function (data){
        $('#postlist').empty();
            $.each(data.posts, function (key, val) {
            //Format date
            var dateString = val.date.split(' ')[0];
            var vdate = dateString.split("-")[1] + " " + monthStrings[parseInt(dateString.split("-")[1])] + ", " + dateString.split("-")[0];
            //Output data collected into page content
                var rtitle = $('<p/>', {'class' : 'vtitle', html: val.title}); rdate = $('<p/>', {'class': 'vdate' , html: vdate});
                rid = $('<a href="#d-posts" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>');
                var rappend = $('<li/>').append(rtitle, rdate);
                console.log($('#postlist').append($(rappend).wrapInner(rid).fadeIn(600)));
                $('#postlist').listview({
                    autodividers: true,
                    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
                        var out = $(li).find(vdate)
                        console.log(out.selector);
                        return out.selector;
                    }
                });
                return (key !== 5);
            });
        $("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh').append('<div class="more-posts" style="text-align: center;">Load more posts...</div>');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Service currently not available, please try again later...");
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Didn't want to leave this unanswered so I have posted below code that worked.

```
$('#postlist').listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
       var out = li.find("p").map(function() {return $(this).text();});
       var outresult = out.get(1);
    return outresult;
    }
});
```